ESP-IDF: Unit tests with unity and C++
I have a project with a few components that I want to test. I've read the documentation and started to create unit tests using unity for one of my component (the component is switches.hpp/cpp). I've created a test folder in the component's folder and added a CMakeLists.txt and the test file as .cpp (since my project is in C++.
switch/test/CMakeLists.txt
idf_component_register(SRC "test_switches.cpp"
                    INCLUDE_DIRS "."
                    REQUIRES unity switches)[/code]

switch/test/test_switches.cpp
#include "unity.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "switches.hpp"

Switches* switches = nullptr;

void setUp(void) {
    switches = Switches::get_instance();

    switches->set_switch_m1_state(SWITCH_M1_A);
    switches->set_switch_m2_state(SWITCH_M2_D);
    switches->set_switch_m3_state(SWITCH_M3_D);
    switches->set_switch_m4_state(SWITCH_M4_GO);
    switches->set_switch_m5_state(SWITCH_M5_F);
}

void tearDown(void) {
    // TODO
}

void test_switch_m1(void) {
    switches->set_switch_m1_state(SWITCH_M1_B);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(SWITCH_M1_B, switches->get_switch_m1_state());
    //TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(1, gpio_get_level(SWITCH_M1_PIN1));
    //TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(0, gpio_get_level(SWITCH_M1_PIN2));
}

extern "C" void app_main(void) {
    UNITY_BEGIN();
    RUN_TEST(test_switch_m1);
    UNITY_END();
}

using VSCode extension of ESP-IDF, with the command pallette and I used the command "ESP-IDF: Unit Test: Build and flash unit test app for testing". This created in the root of the project a unity-app folder with a project to start the unit tests. I modified the main file :
unity-app/main/test_app_main.c
/*
 * SPDX-FileCopyrightText: 2015-2021 Espressif Systems (Shanghai) CO LTD
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

#include "unity.h"

static void print_banner(const char* text)
{
    printf("\n#### %s #####\n\n", text);
}

void app_main(void)
{
    print_banner("Unity test runner");
    printf("Total test count: %d\n", unity_get_test_count());

    UNITY_BEGIN();
    unity_run_all_tests();
    UNITY_END();
    
    unity_run_menu();
}

And also modified the CMakeLists.txt of the unit test project :
# The following lines of boilerplate have to be in your project's
# CMakeLists in this exact order for cmake to work correctly
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/version.cmake)

# Add newly added components to one of these lines:
# 1. Add here if the component is compatible with IDF >= v4.3
set(EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS "../components")

set(TEST_COMPONENTS switches)

include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(test_app_main)

When the unit test app built and flashed onto the ESP32-S3 Mini I got, it printed and ran correctly but didn't find the test I wrote for the switches. I have tried to modify the EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS and TEST_COMPONENTS name multiple times without success. I can't seem to understand why it doesn't work. Maybe it's because I used C++ instead of C, but I have no choice.

I found a solution, I added this line in the project's CMakeLists.txt and it worked. This doesn't appear in the unit test example.
set(EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS "$ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/unit-test-app/components" "main")

This is the final CMakeLists.txt for the project (root/CMakeLists.txt) :
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS "$ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/unit-test-app/components" "main")

include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(la-mine-des-CFK)


Take a look at this example from esp-idf repository: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/system/unit_test. It is very similar to your code but it is divided into application project and test project which are flashed separately.

Thank you for the suggestion. I was already using this repository to help me get the correct structure for the tests to work, since they work in this project. However, I don't think that the problem is the structure, the test project can be flashed but it doesn't find the tests I've written.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Per the documentation for unit-tests,
your tests should use the macro TEST_CASE() so that the test runner can find them.
TEST_CASE("test name", "[module name]")
{
        // Add test here
}

There is no need to add a main function with UNITY_BEGIN() and ​UNITY_END() in each test case. unity_platform.c will run UNITY_BEGIN() autonomously, and run the test cases, then call ​UNITY_END().
Also see the example test file.
That is how your switch/test/test_switches.cpp should be structured.
